# (source) in Clojure giving "not found" for REPL-defined functions

Tags: clojure

I defn a function in a REPL.  The function works fine and all is well.  But my REPL window is small and after exercising my function for a while I wanted to just look at the source.  There is a source function, great.  But wait...

```
(defn print-seq [s]
  (when (seq s)
    (prn (first s))
    (recur (rest s))))
=> #'user/print-seq
(source user/print-seq)
Source not found
=> nil
```

What went wrong here?  `(source source)` works fine, so its not that I can't execute source.  There's something I don't get here.  Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.repl/source):

> Prints the source code for the given symbol, if it can find it.
>   This requires that the symbol resolve to a Var **defined in a
>   namespace for which the .clj is in the classpath**.

Functions defined in the REPL don't have an associated `.clj` file in the classpath.

If you want to verify this, consider reading the output of `(source 'source-fn)`; on its face, this function works if and only if there is a **.clj** file in the source path.